# ¿Consulta quitando los protected $with del modelo - Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola a todos esta vez acudo a ustedes por lo siguiente, tengo el siguiente modelo, en el como muestro en el código, tengo una relacion de employee y candidates al hacer consultas utilizando el modelo me trae también los de la relación ya que estan delcarados en pretected $with = ['employee', 'candidates'] y quiero evitar esto sin eliminar el protected claro:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use  App\Models\Candidate;
class CandidateExam extends Model
{
    protected $table ="candidate_exams";

    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['candidate_id', 'exam_id','score','active','total_questions'];

    protected $with = ['Employee','Candidates'];


    public function Employee(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Employee', 'id', 'candidate_id');
    }

    public function Candidates(){
        return $this->hasMany(Candidate::class, 'id', 'candidate_id');
    }

}
```

En mi controlador estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
   public function startExam(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $personalExam = CandidateExam::where('candidate_id', $request->candidate_id)
                ->where('exam_id', $request->exam_id)
                ->first();

            DB::commit();

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'examPersonal' => $personalExam,
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => $e->getMessage()
            ]);
        }
    }
```

La consulta funciona muy bien el problema es que no quiero las consultas de la relación del modelo declarados en el **protected $with** que por defecto al hacer cualquier consulta utilizando eloquent me las trae por defecto ¿Hay alguna forma de evitar esto en mi consulta?
De ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para quitar relaciones especificas debes utilizar el método `without('NOMBRE_RELACION')` y `withOnly('NOMBRE_RELACION')` si quieres anular todos los elementos dentro de la propiedad `$with` y cargar alguno en particular.

> Recuerda que también existe [load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading), que es una carga ansiosa perezosa y te permitirá cargar las relaciones más tarde sin tener el problema de N+1.

Lo anterior en vista a que quizá tener la propiedad `$with` cargando las relaciones por defecto no sea lo más optimo.

**Ejemplo:**

```
$books = Book::without('author')->get();

$books = Book::withOnly('genre')->get();
```

obs: Ambos métodos soportan un array de N relaciones.

Para más información puedes revisar la [documentación oficial de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).